# Specific example of a problem that shows why **NP** isn't low for itself

Tags: complexity-theory, oracle-machines, relativization

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_(complexity))

> Every class which is low for itself is closed under complement, provided that it is powerful enough to negate the boolean result. This implies that **NP** isn't low for itself unless **NP** = **co-NP**, which is considered unlikely... .

This line of reasoning is a bit abstract for me. Is there a concrete example of a simple problem that can be shown to be in $\textbf{NP}^\textbf{NP} \setminus \textbf{NP}$ under reasonable assumptions? That is, a problem that can't be solved efficiently by a nondeterministic Turing machine, but *can* be solved efficiently by a NTM with oracle access to *another* NTM?

Comment: We don't know whether $\textbf{NP}^\textbf{NP} \neq \textbf{NP}$, so it will be hard coming up with such an example.   Note that $\textbf{NP}^\textbf{NP} = \Sigma^P_2$ (the second level of the polynomial hierarchy, $\textbf{PH}$).

Comment: @PålGD Yeah, that's why I said "under reasonable assumptions". Certainly no example can be shown to work unconditionally. Maybe it's still a hard question though.

Comment: But there are many problems (e.g. maxmin problems) that are complete for $\Sigma^P_2$.

Comment: Take a look at the first reference in a [previous answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/41533/4249).

Comment: @PålGD Thanks, but understanding those examples requires going through reductions complicated enough that I lose all the intuition. By a "simple" example I mean one which I can understand by directly thinking about the behavior of a NTM, without needing to go through a lot of nonobvious other results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Pål GD mentions in the comments, $\mathsf{NP}^\mathsf{NP}$ is usually knows as $\mathsf{\Sigma}_2^P$, the second level of the polynomial hierarchy. If $L$ is any $\mathsf{\Sigma}_2^P$ complete problem, then $\mathsf{NP} \neq \mathsf{\Sigma}_2^P$ is *equivalent* to $L \in \mathsf{\Sigma}_2^P \setminus \mathsf{NP}$. So any $\mathsf{\Sigma}_2^P$-complete problem is a concrete example for a problem in $\mathsf{\Sigma}_2^P \setminus \mathsf{NP}$ under the reasonable assumption that $\mathsf{\Sigma}_2^P \setminus \mathsf{NP} \neq \emptyset$. In other words, these are the problems "most likely" to be the concrete examples you seek.

One canonical complete problem for $\mathsf{\Sigma}_2^P$ is $\exists \forall\mathsf{SAT}$: given a formula $\varphi$ on variables $\vec{x},\vec{y}$, is is true that there exists an assignment $\alpha$ to $\vec{x}$ such that $\varphi|_{\vec{x} = \alpha}$ becomes a tautology? It is easy to see that this can be solved by an $\mathsf{NP}^\mathsf{NP}$ machine: the machine guesses $\alpha$, and uses the oracle to verify that $(\lnot \varphi)|_{\vec{x} = \alpha}$ is unsatisfiable.

Generally speaking, the assumption $\mathsf{NP} \neq \mathsf{\Sigma}_2^P$ seems stronger than $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$, and when proving conditional results, we prefer assuming the latter rather than the former. But it is generally conjectured that the entire polynomial hierarchy is strict, a much stronger assumption.